# How to solve error Sequence contains more than one matching element in Nopcommerce Plugin Creation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nopcommerce

I have created one module in nopcommerce in which I want to create one file.

I have created following files for that:

**Services files, Data file, Domain file, ObjectContext file, Provider
file Controller, model & view**

But when I am trying to install that plugin it gives an error like following:

> Sequence contains more than one matching element

I don't understand why this error occurs.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

You can see at the log to get the full error. And you can add a breakpoint in the Install() method to understand where the error occurred.

Comment: Hey i have checked this in Log but does not find proper reason why it fires an error. Can you please share causes why this error can occur?

Answer (score 0):

It means that your plugin tries to add some database during installation but this table ALREADY exists. Manually delete it and try installing the plugin one more time